# Getting the printers on which I have rights to access

Tags: c#, active-directory, group-policy, gpo

I have a server, when user logs in, a logon script is executed that loads the printers which the user have rights on. This is done using GPO. So when the user is logged in, he can see the printers he is allowed to use.

What I need to do is to load these printers in a C# application. I have been trying to enumerate the properties of group policy container using (objectClass=groupPolicyContainer) filter but I am not able to find the printers which I (current user) have access to.

Comment: Seems very impractical.  Maybe you can find the printer object, but how it the user going to find the printer back?

Comment: Actually I am able to get the printers using active directory, but to be sure that only those printers on which I have rights I want to be able to get the GPO info about the printers for my user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI for that and especialy [WIN32_Printer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class :

```
using System.Management;

namespace WMIQuery
{
  class WmiQuery
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      /* On the local computer loged as current user
       */
      ObjectQuery oQuery0 = new ObjectQuery(@"select * from Win32_printer where shared=true");
      ManagementObjectSearcher searcher0 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oQuery0);

      foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher0.Get())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("--> {0} ({1})", queryObj["Name"], queryObj["ShareName"]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am having a situation where I need to list the printers from active directory that too with rights for me to access whereas this code is giving me the list of installed network printers.

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I understand GPOs contents are not stored in Active-Directory. Only refences are stored inside the AD, The contents are stored on the server file system, ans are loaded into registry (or whatever) at logon.

Comment: So how could I get the registry information about the allowed printers.

Comment: There is somethib I don't understand. In you environment, how the user know that an installed network printer is allowed or not  for him.